# How to stop excel from autoconversion

Tags: excel

I need to write binary data in 64 bits like 0000000000000010, 0000000000000011 etc, but when I write them, it gets automatically converted to 10, 11 respectively. Also, when I write a huge number, like 100000000000 it gets converted to 1E+11.

How can I stop excel from converting? I would need to show them in all 64 binary digits only and not in abbreviated form.

Comment: You can always just go into a cell and type ="0000000000010" and so on.

Comment: The number 100000000000 *is* the number 1 E 11, so nothing has been converted. It is merely displayed in a different format. You can change the formatting of how numbers are displayed in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the cells in your worksheet, right click and select "Text" from the list of category, click ok and you are ready to insert the binary numbers that you want.